# Calculate work progress in percentage of batches that contain tasks and task contain sub tasks

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to calculate work progress in percentage.  I have multiple batches, and each batch contains a set of tasks and each task also contains a set of sub tasks.  Below code is the best I could do.  Is there any more efficient way to do this?

I just edited the code using the Math static method to do help with rounding and getting the next up value.

```
    double numOfBatches = 3;
    double weightOfEachBatch = (1*100)/numOfBatches;

    double numOfTasksInEachBatch = 1;
    double weightOfEachTask =
        (1*weightOfEachBatch)/numOfTasksInEachBatch;

    double numOfSubTasksInEachTask = 2;
    double weightOfEachSubTask =
        (1*weightOfEachTask)/numOfSubTasksInEachTask;

    System.out.println("Weight of each batch: " + weightOfEachBatch + "%");
    System.out.println("Weight of each task: " + weightOfEachTask + "%");
    System.out.println("Weight of each sub task: " + weightOfEachSubTask + "%");

    double fromBatchWeight = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfBatches; i++) {

        double toBatchWeight = weightOfEachBatch * i;
        System.out.println(
                "Batch " + i +
                " from " + Math.floor(fromBatchWeight) +
                "% to " + Math.floor(toBatchWeight) + "%");

        double fromTaskWeight = fromBatchWeight;
        for(int j = 1; j <= numOfTasksInEachBatch; j++) {

            double toTaskWeight = (weightOfEachTask * j) + fromBatchWeight;
            System.out.println(
                    "\tTask " + j +
                    " from " + Math.floor(fromTaskWeight) +
                    "% to " + Math.floor(toTaskWeight) + "%");

            double fromSubTaskWeight = fromTaskWeight;
            for(int k = 1; k <= numOfSubTasksInEachTask; k++) {

                double toSubTaskWeight = (weightOfEachSubTask * k) + fromTaskWeight;
                System.out.println(
                        "\t\tSub Task " + k +
                        " from " + Math.floor(fromSubTaskWeight) +
                        "% to " + Math.floor(toSubTaskWeight) + "%");

                fromSubTaskWeight = Math.nextUp(toSubTaskWeight);
            }

            fromTaskWeight = Math.nextUp(toTaskWeight);
        }

        fromBatchWeight = Math.nextUp(toBatchWeight);
    }
```

The output looks like this

```
Weight of each batch: 33.333333333333336%
Weight of each task: 33.333333333333336%
Weight of each sub task: 16.666666666666668%
Batch 1 from 0.0% to 33.0%
    Task 1 from 0.0% to 33.0%
        Sub Task 1 from 0.0% to 16.0%
        Sub Task 2 from 16.0% to 33.0%
Batch 2 from 33.0% to 66.0%
    Task 1 from 33.0% to 66.0%
        Sub Task 1 from 33.0% to 50.0%
        Sub Task 2 from 50.0% to 66.0%
Batch 3 from 66.0% to 100.0%
    Task 1 from 66.0% to 100.0%
        Sub Task 1 from 66.0% to 83.0%
        Sub Task 2 from 83.0% to 100.0%
```

Comment: What if different batches have a different number of tasks? What if different tasks have a different number of subtasks? Or is that not an issue for what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

1. ```
   System.out.println("\t\tSub Task " + k + " from " + Math.floor(fromSubTaskWeight) + "% to "
       + Math.floor(toSubTaskWeight) + "%");
   ```

   I'd use `System.out.format` here, it's easier to read than string concatenation:

   ```
   System.out.format("\t\tSub Task %d from %f%% to %f%%%n", 
       k, Math.floor(fromSubTaskWeight), Math.floor(toSubTaskWeight));
   ```

   With that you can easily format floating numbers.

   ```
   Weight of each task: 33,333333%
   Weight of each sub task: 16,666667%
   ```

   Could be a readable

   ```
   Weight of each task: 33,33%
   Weight of each sub task: 16,67%
   ```

   With

   ```
   System.out.format("Weight of each task: %.2f%%%n", weightOfEachTask);
   System.out.format("Weight of each sub task: %.2f%%%n", weightOfEachSubTask);
   ```
2. Having three nested for loops is hard to read. I'd try to extract out a `printSubtaskWeights` and a `printTaskWeights` method.
3. I've seen earlier the `numOfSubTasksInEachTask` style variables but I've found `subTasksInEachTaskNumber` more easier to work with. Maybe because if more than one variable starts with `numOf` it's hard to differentiate them.
4. `i`, `j`, `k` variables could be more descriptive and could express their purpose. For example, 
   `batchNumber`, `taskNumber` and `subtaskNumber`.
5. Batches, tasks and subtasks looks very similar. I'd try to create a common abstraction for them and use that three times instead of duplication.

   ```
   public class Item {

       private int subItemCount;
       private double weight;

       public Item(final int subItemCount, double weight) {
           super();
           this.subItemCount = subItemCount;
           this.weight = weight;
       }

       public int getSubItemCount() {
           return subItemCount;
       }

       public double getOneSubItemWeight() {
           final double subItemWeight = (1 * weight) / subItemCount;
           return subItemWeight;
       }

       public String getWeightInfo() {
           return String.format("Weight of each %s: %.2f%%", 
               name, getOneSubItemWeight());
       }
   }
   ```

   (I'd call it `Task` but it hasn't already been used.)

   I started refactoring the code but I guess I won't finish it. The beginning of the code looked like this:

   ```
   final Item batches = new Item(3, 100);
   final Item tasks = new Item(1, batches.getOneSubItemWeight());
   final Item subtasks = new Item(2, tasks.getOneSubItemWeight());
   ```

   `100` is the batches' weight, tasks and subtasks inherit the weight of their parents.

   Note that the duplicated `Weight of each` print statement was also moved to the `Item` class.

   I'd also try to move a loop into the `Item` class and call subitem printing from that method. I'd reduce the number of loops to one. Something like this:

   ```
   public class Item {

       private final Item subitems;
       ...

       public void print(double fromWeight) {
           for (int item = 1; item <= itemCount; item++) {

               double toWeight = getItemWeight() * item;
               System.out.format("%s %d from %f%% to %f%%%n", 
                   name, item, Math.floor(fromBatchWeight),
                   Math.floor(toBatchWeight));

               if (subitems != null) {
                   subitems.print(fromWeight);
               }
               fromWeight = Math.nextUp(toWeight);
       }
   }
   ```